# Quadratic equations in two or more variables

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, cubics

Which of the following is a quadratic equation and why?

$$yx^2+x-1=0$$
$$x^2+x-y=0$$

where $x$ and $y$ are variables.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Both are quadratic equations in the variable $x$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange them to put $y$ as the subject and you'll quickly see which is quadratic. A quadratic has the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$

For the first, we get:
$$yx^2+x-1=0\to yx^2=1-x\to y=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}$$
Certainly not a quadratic.

For the second we get:
$$x^2+x-y=0\to x^2+x=y\to y=x^2+x$$

This is a quadratic, with $a=1,b=1,c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

First one is a cubic equation in two variables $x$ and $y$ as the first term has degree $3$ the second one is quadratic equation in two variables.